# Do time-based workflow rules cause triggers to fire?

Tags: trigger, time-dependent-workflow, order-of-execution

I am wondering if time-based workflow rules cause triggers to fire.  The use-case is I use a trigger to look for a field to be checked and then send an email out via a trigger (workflow rule is not an option because it requires BCC addresses).  The email also looks for a particular attachment in the notes and attachments section of the opportunity.  This attachment is automatically uploaded via a third-party, but it takes a few seconds for it to show up... currently, the email gets sent out before the attachment is uploaded.

I am wondering if a time-based workflow rule to update a field on the opportunity will still cause the trigger to fire.  If so, I believe this would solve my issue of the email being sent out before the attachment is there.

Comment: If the Time-Based Workflows update any records in an object and if there is a trigger on update, then yes. They would execute the triggers on the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any field update from a `Workflow Rule`/`Process Builder`/`Apex Trigger` will cause update triggers on affected records to fire.

Comment: Hi @Adrian , I have got similar scenario where time based WF rule updates a field on some records at certain time as per rule criteria but trigger(after update) is not executing due to that field update. While manually updating the records, fires the trigger correctly. What should I check? Also is there any other way to fire the trigger in that case?

Comment: Please try to avoid asking complex questions via `Comment`. If you want to dig into something you are investigating, please ask a new `Question` instead.